# State getting reset to 0 after render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am rendering photos from unsplash api. And I am keeping the index of the photos to be used in the lightbox, after the initial render state of imageindex goes back to 0, how can I retain its value?
I will show some code

```
 const ImageList = ({ image, isLoaded }) => {
      const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);
      const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState('false');
const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    setImageIndex(e.target.id);
  };

  const imgs = image.map((img, index) => (
    <img
      id={index}
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.small}
      onClick={onClickHandler}

if (isOpen === true) {
    return (
      <Lightbox

        onCloseRequest={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        mainSrc={image[imageIndex].urls.regular}
        onMoveNextRequest={() => setImageIndex((imageIndex + 1) % image.length)}
        onMovePrevRequest={() => setImageIndex((imageIndex + image.length - 1) % image.length)}
        nextSrc={image[(imageIndex + 1) % image.length].urls.regular}
        prevSrc={image[(imageIndex + image.length - 1) % image.length].urls.regular}

      />
```

Comment: " after the initial render state, imageIndex goes back to 0 ". That makes sense, the initial render would use whatever you set as the default value. Unless you plan on using some data storage that keeps track of the last used selected item.

Comment: What will you advice me to do?

Comment: Try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after the initial render state, imageIndex goes back to 0.

That makes sense, the initial render would use whatever you set as the default value. You can use something like `local storage` to help you keep track of the index of the last used item. It's a bit primitive, but until you integrate something like `Node/MongoDB` for database collections, this will be perfect.

In your component, import `useEffect()` from React. This hook lets us execute some logic any time the `state-index` value changes, or anything else you might have in mind.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
```

Then inside your component, define two `useEffect()` blocks.

**Getting last used index from `localStorage` on intitial load:**

```
useEffect(() => {
   const lastIndex = localStorage.getItem("index", imageIndex)
   setImageIndex(imageIndex)
}, []) //set as an empty array so it will only execute once.
```

**Saving index to `localStorage` on change:**

```
useEffect(() => {
   localStorage.setItem("index", imageIndex)
}, [imageIndex]) //define values to subscribe to here. Will execute anytime value changes.
```